# SimpleXMLElement unset() not working

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file populated with keys and once a particular key has been used it will be deleted from the xml file. The code below runs, but does not delete the key from the xml file. I've read here on SO that maybe putting an "&" in the `foreach()` will ensure that I'm working with the actual xml file data rather than the temporary data created by the `foreach()`, but all I get when I run this code is;

`Fatal error: An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference in ....`

xml file

```
<proctor>
    <keys>
        <key>afvr3e</key>
        <key>578jyd</key>
        <key>hnr6rg</key>
        <key>890kg7</key>
        <key>hn3rgd</key>
    </keys>
</proctor>
```

php index file

```
$key = new ProctorKey('proctorKey.xml');
$key->DeleteKey('hnr6rg');
```

php class file

```
class ProctorKey
{
    private $file;
    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }
    public function DeleteKey($keyToDelete)
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($this->file)or die("Error: Cannot create object"); 
        /* this throws a fatal error
        *  foreach($xml->keys as &key)
        */
        foreach($xml->keys->key as $key)
        {
            if($key==$keyToDelete)
            {
                unset($key); 
                print('found');
            }
        }
        return $this->FormatXML($xml->asXML());
    }
    private function FormatXML($data)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $dom->loadXML($data);
        $dom->save($this->file);
        $response = ($dom)?true:false;
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet below helps in two keys ways:

- it uses XPath to iterate over an array containing only the `key` element(s) that you wish to delete
- it calls `unset` on the actual element rather than the `$key` variable (it's a quirk of `SimpleXMLElement` being an iterable object too).

**Snippet**

```
foreach($xml->xpath("keys/key[.='$keyToDelete']") as $key)
{
    unset($key[0]); 
}
```

Comment: Hey salathe, unfortunately this did not work. I tried to delete another key to make sure anything whacky wasn't happening on my end. I'm going to read up on xpath, I like how the code looks :)

Comment: You say it didn't work, what did it do?  It is fine for me -- http://codepad.viper-7.com/w11l8U

Comment: When I run the code it runs fine, no errors. But, when I look at the xml file I still see the key. I noticed that your code is a little different on codepad ... I am going to make a quick test file exactly the way you have it there and see what happens. I will be right back ;)

Comment: Ahhhhh I am dumb today .. I commented out the return that actually saves the file. You are correct sir, it runs perfect. Thank you so much. If your ever doing some Archaeolgy here in Utah stop buy and I will buy you a beer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is wrong

Replace

```
    foreach($xml->keys->key as $key)
    {
        if($key==$keyToDelete)
        {
            unset($key);
            print('found');
        }
    }
```

With

```
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($xml->keys->key); $i++)
    {
        if($xml->keys->key[$i] == $keyToDelete)
        {
            unset($xml->keys->key[$i]);
            print('found');
        }
    }
```

Thanks

:)

Comment: Thanks Baba, but it still did not remove the key. When I run the script it prints 'found', but it didn't remove it from the file :(

Answer (score -1):

First of all, modifying a collection on which you're iterating now may lead to unpredictable behaviour. Secondly, xml objects may work not exactly just plain std objects. Maybe, `SimpleXML` is different, but in `XML DOM`, which I used one should call special method like `removeChildNode`, not just an `unset`.

Comment: I have read many times that XML DOM is a better solution ... I just thought maybe there was something easy I was missing. I am reading up on XML DOM as we speak so I can get this to work. why do they call it SimpleXML if it's really not that simple? lol

Comment: Actually it is "lighter" simple for trivial operations. When I chose, I decided to use XML DOM, cause it just like HTML DOM in js, which I already knew.

Comment: Some people consider suggesting another instrument instead of helping with current as **bad thing**. Don't bother.

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement` has its own internal handler called when `unset()` is used, it just needs to be executed on the correct object.